# Getting a common error (Error Error: Compile Error: Variable does not exist: name at line 8 column 15 )

Tags: trigger

```
trigger Candidate on Candidate__c (before update) {
list<Backup_Candidates__c > cbl= new list<Backup_Candidates__c >();

list<Candidate__c > lc= trigger.old;
for(Candidate__c  c : lc)
{
Backup_Candidates__c lbc= new Backup_Candidates__c();
lbc.name = lc.name;
lbc.Phone__c=lc.Candidate_Phone__c;
lbc.ID__c=lc.Candidate_Id__c;
lbc.Percentage__c=lc.Percentage__c;
cbl.add(lbc);
}
insert cbl ;

}
```

i tried to resolve but still it is throwing error please help me out

Answer (score 3):

The variable `lc` is a list and `for(Candidate__c  c : lc)` iterates over each item so in the body of the for loop it is the variable `c` that you should be using:

```
lbc.name = c.name;
lbc.Phone__c = c.Candidate_Phone__c;
...
```

Consistent naming convention of list and item variables can help avoid this sort of mistake.